# Application Insight asp.net core 6.0 RequestTelemetry not logging Operation_id when hosted in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using custom middleware to log request/responses from my Web API. using `TrackRequest(requestTelemetry)`,I am adding few `custom properties` and `operation_name` in `requestTelemetry`. When i host web API in Azure App Service I can see operation_id logged in request table, but when I host same code in Service Fabric (Kestrel) request telemetry doesn't have Operation_id, only Dependency telemetry have operation_id.

There are lot of code changes done and earlier `operation_id`, and `parentOperation_id` was written in Request table and dependency table. because of some code changes now operation_id and parentOperation_Id are not written in AI tables.

Is there any `config/code` for AI to automatically log `operationId`. some of the articles mentioned that with TrackRequest, servcie code has to explicitly add operation_Id, but earlier don't think any explicit add was done and still operation_id was getting logged.

Comment: Could you please share the code which you have tried and also share the Configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the `operation_id` and `parentOperation_id` in Local traces.

[image]

But unable to see the same trace in Application Insights initially.

In `Transaction Search` => Click on any of the `trace/request` => click on Show all.

[image]

Now Iam able to see the same trace which I have seen in Local.

[image]

> some of the articles mentioned that with TrackRequest, servcie code has to explicitly add operation_Id,

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking?source=recommendations#http-request-in-owin-self-hosted-app), we an explicitly add the code to log `operation_id`, and `parentOperation_id`.

Use the below code to explicitly log `operation_id` and `parentOperation_id`.

***`Controller.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OperationID.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {  

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _tc;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, TelemetryClient tc)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tc = tc;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var operation_id = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            var parentOperation_id = Activity.Current?.ParentId ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            _tc.TrackTrace($"operation_id: {operation_id}, parentOperation_id: {parentOperation_id}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Log operation_id: {operation_id}, parentOperation_id: {parentOperation_id}");
            var requestTelemetry = HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
            _tc.TrackRequest(requestTelemetry);

            _logger.LogInformation("GetWeatherForecast Logs");
         ----------
         ----------
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harshitha, in my case i have checked in logs table and local debug is also not logging operation_id. i am not using TelemetryClient.StartOperation or telemetryClient.StopOperation.  In the doc sample you have shared, they are not using TrackRequest. I have added code in https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2805

Comment: Also share your configuration file.

Comment: harshitha i have updated question based on my debugging. Missing operation_id is happening only when i am hosting my web api in Service Fabric (kestrel). But same code when hosted in Azure App Service, logs  have Operation_id in request table.  in {sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking?source=recommendations#http-request-in-owin-self-hosted-app) that you shared can you suggest where/how Telemetry.TrackRequest should be called. StopOperation will log to request?

Comment: Add `Telemetry.TrackRequest` in the controller class.

Comment: I am able to see the `operation_id` and `parentoperation_id` even for a  [Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0VL1.png) with the code which I have provided.

Comment: Can you share your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: I don't have appseting.json. I have cutom config file in a custom nested folder, in statup I read that file and create my config class. then i use that config file to initialize telemetry as shown in [code] (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2805)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254858/discussion-between-harshitha-and-user9297554).

Comment: Harshitha, i tried the suggestion and used startOperation and stopOperation in my middleware. After that OperationId is gettgin logged in Request table (for web api hosted in Service fabric), but multiple requests (for multiple Actions) are having the same operationId (but their parentId are different). I have not explicitly set operationId and I am using ASP.net 6 core

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot  of the result.And share how you have set the id's in Middleware.